# Error in qplot() in R programing

Tags: r

Am trying to plot histogram for the following function which simulates a die experiment

```
rm(list=ls())
roll<-function()
{
sample(1:6,size = 2,replace = 2)
}
rolls<-replicate(10000,roll())
qplot(rolls,aes(x=rolls),binwidth=1)
```

am getting the following error "Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x"

please help.

Comment: This is not the error that I have, Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""uneval"" to a data.frame.

Comment: Anyway this kind of mistakes can be solved using ggplot and the parameter stat="identity"

Comment: Have a look at `rolls`, or `names(rolls)`: there is no variable called "rolls". What is your expected output? Histogramm over all values or for each of the 2 values you draw?

Comment: btw: `replace` within `sample` should be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, anything else does not make sense. Read `?sample`.

Answer (score 1):

Check `?qplot`. The first and the second arguments are `x` and `y`. Anyway, if you are simulating the die experiment 10,000 times, you don't need to define your function and use `replicate`. Just specify `size = 10000` in `sample()`.

```
rm(list=ls())

rolls <- sample(1:6,size = 10000 ,replace = TRUE)
qplot(rolls, binwidth = 1)
```